# change margins of a template to the normal DIN-A4 standard

Tags: margins, covers

recently I found a template for a cover sheet. The code is written blow. Unfortunately, it is quite far away from being minimal, but I wanted to show you the whole design. My "problem" now is the following: I would like to have the normal margins of DIN-A4-Paper, but the template has smaller margins or even no margin at some sides of the sheet. 
I expect the solution of the problem to be contained in the "adjust the page margins"-section, but I don't know, how to change it appropriately. Perhaps you can help me. (The formatting of the page should remain constant, I would only like to have the normal margin on each side.)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{scrartcl}
% -------------------------------------------------
% character encoding
% -------------------------------------------------
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1,ansinew]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{framed}
\pagestyle{empty}
% -------------------------------------------------
% adjust the page margins
% -------------------------------------------------
\usepackage[scale=1]{geometry}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\addtolength{\parskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\footskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}
\setlength{\topskip}{0pt}
% -------------------------------------------------
% positioning of text elements
% -------------------------------------------------
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}
\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{1cm}
\setlength{\TPVertModule}{\TPHorizModule}
%
% -------------------------------------------------
% personal data
% -------------------------------------------------
\def\firstname{Max}
\def\familyname{Mustermann}
\def\FileAuthor{\firstname \familyname}
\def\FileSubject{Cover}
%
% -------------------------------------------------
% Font
% -------------------------------------------------
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{pcr}
%
% -------------------------------------------------
% from moderncvstylecasual.sty:
% -------------------------------------------------
\definecolor{blau}{rgb}{0.20,0.40,0.65}
\definecolor{hellblau}{rgb}{0.25,0.50,0.75}
\definecolor{dunkelgrau}{rgb}{0.35,0.35,0.35}
\definecolor{hellgrau}{rgb}{0.45,0.45,0.45}
\definecolor{schwarz}{rgb}{0,0,0}
\newcommand*{\firstnamefont}{\fontsize{25}{27}\sffamily\mdseries\upshape}
\newcommand*{\familynamefont}{\firstnamefont}
\newcommand*{\titel}{\fontsize{25}{27}\mdseries\upshape}
\newcommand*{\inhalt}{\fontsize{15}{17}\mdseries\upshape}
%
\begin{document}
\sffamily
%
% -------------------------------------------------
% title
% -------------------------------------------------
\begin{textblock}{10}(1,2)
\color{dunkelgrau}{
\bfseries \begin{Large}\titel{Long Title ABCD}\end{Large}}
\end{textblock}
%
% -------------------------------------------------
% table of contents
% -------------------------------------------------
%\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{}

\begin{textblock}{10}(12.9,21)
\color{blau}{\inhalt{
\begin{itemize}\setlength{\itemsep}{-1pt}
    \item Item A
    \vspace{0.1cm}
    \item Very Long Item B
    \vspace{0.1cm}      
    \item Item C
    \vspace{0.1cm}      
    \item Item D
    \vspace{0.1cm}      
    \item Long Item E
    \vspace{0.1cm}      
    \item Very Long Item F
    \vspace{0.1cm}      
    \item Long Item G
    \vspace{0.1cm}      
    \item Long Item H
\end{itemize}
}}
\end{textblock}
%
% -------------------------------------------------
% vertical line
% -------------------------------------------------
\begin{textblock}{1}(13.5,0)
\color{hellblau}{\vrule width 2pt height 21cm}
\end{textblock}
% -------------------------------------------------
% picture
% -------------------------------------------------
\begin{textblock}{3}(1,4)
\color{schwarz}{\fbox{\includegraphics[width=11cm]{picture}}}
\end{textblock}
%
% -------------------------------------------------
% address
% -------------------------------------------------
\begin{textblock}{9.7}(1,16.2)
\color{hellblau}{\begin{flushleft}
    \vspace{-3.5cm}
    {\bfseries \begin{large}\firstnamefont{\color{hellgrau}{\firstname}}~\familynamefont{\color{dunkelgrau}{\familyname}}\end{large}}\\[.35ex]
    \huge\itshape%
    Musterstraße 1\\
    12345 Musterstadt\\[.35ex]
    \Mobilefone~{ABCD}\\
    \Letter~{verylongaddress@abc.com}
\end{flushleft}}
\end{textblock}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What are normal margins of DIN-A4 paper? ;-)

Comment: From my point of view: the "normal" margins that belong to the option a4paper of the document class.

Comment: I would say, you would get them in a MWE just using `scrartcl` class and `\usepackage[verbose]{geometry}` and some dummy output, i.e. `\blindtext` from the package

Comment: If I write your proposal instead of the line from my template \usepackage[scale=1]{geometry}, then a huge amount of lines and frames appear in the pdf-output file, but the page itself still does not respect the margins.

Comment: `showframe=true` is only for debugging and testing ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following MWE with `scrartcl` class and `a4` paper option generates a output on terminal, shown below.

```
\documentclass[paper=a4]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage[showframe=true,verbose]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

> - \paperwidth=597.50793pt
> - \paperheight=845.04694pt
> - \textwidth=418.25372pt
> - \textheight=591.53027pt
> - \oddsidemargin=17.35712pt
> - \evensidemargin=17.35712pt
> - \topmargin=-8.26335pt
> - \headheight=17.0pt
> - \headsep=20.40001pt
> - \topskip=11.0pt
> - \footskip=47.6pt
> - \marginparwidth=59.7508pt
> - \marginparsep=12.8401pt
> - \columnsep=10.0pt
> - \skip\footins=10.0pt plus 4.0pt minus 2.0pt
> - \hoffset=0.0pt
> - \voffset=0.0pt
> - \mag=1000
> - \@twocolumnfalse
> - \@twosidefalse
> - \@mparswitchfalse
> - \@reversemarginfalse

Important for the margins are `\oddsidemargin`, `\evensidemargin` (being equal in this case), and `\topmargin`, as well as the `\marginparwidth` and `\marginparsep`

This is the output of the MWE by the OP, just to clearify what we are talking about:

[image]

Comment: Okay, this looks good, but how can I define them? Is it each time a command like \setlenght{...}{...}?

Comment: @Phil: You don't have too :D Just omit that `\setlength` stuff in your code and you should get the standard margins ;-) (Well apart from `\setlength{\parindent}` perhaps.) In fact, you don't even need the geometry package, since the KOMA classes are defined to provide **normal** margins for the corresponding paper format

Comment: I meant of course: You don't have to ;-) I am typing too fast :D

Comment: Sorry, but even if I get rid of the complete "adjust the page margins" stuff, some elements appear on the margins.

Comment: @Phil: If I compile your document, there is huge image with text on the left side and a list of items on the right side.

Comment: You are right, but for example the distance of the picture and the text from the left margin is too small. Otherwise there is a blue line which starts at the top of the page without respecting the margin. I would like to have the same page with same proportions, but on each side the correct margin, if this is possible.

Comment: @Phil: I see. I suppose one source of the error might be a possible  wrong usage of `textpos`, but I am no expert regarding that.

Comment: Where should the blue line appear? Left, right, not at all? Where should the item list appear, below the image?

Comment: You were right, the problem appeared as a consequence of the coordinates of the textblocks. The origin of these coordinates is situated at the top left corner of the paper without respecting any margin. So, now al works fine. Thanks a lot.